# CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: could not find driver

Tags: yii

I use server ubuntu 11.04 install apache2 . I have problem when connect to database. this is my error :

```
CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: could not find driver
```

this is mycode connect to database :

```
 'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=server$
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '*****',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),
```

Please help me, thank all so much

Comment: Check out your php-pdo-mysql & php-mysqln drivers to php.ini

Comment: CDbConnection is for yii1 not yii2

Comment: @Evgeniy Tkachenko how to check. I don't know plesase help me

Answer (score 0):

Run in console

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
sudo service apache2 restart
```

or for native mysql driver

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: i have error : php5-mysqlnd : Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.14) but 5.5.12+dfsg-2ubuntu4.3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: I 've done but the problem is not resolution. when i use phpinfor() this is infor : PDO drivers no value

Comment: This problem is packages on ubuntu 11.04. Update your system to current stable